# How do I get the jquery script "chosen" to work in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/chosen.min.js" ></script>

[...]

<asp:ListBox class="chosen-select" ID="lbCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDropDownListCategory" 
SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="IdCategory"></asp:ListBox>

<script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
```

I have the js in the path that I wrote and the script dosen't work, I tried to search, but everthing I found doesn't fix it, could someone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see as issues.

1. There is no `chosen.min.js` in the files. There is the `chosen.jquery.min.js` and some others.
2. The `AutoPostBack="true"` will not work if you use the chosen plugin because the plugin redesign the original control witch now is hidden. Also you use `SelectionMode="Multiple"` so if the auto post back work in every click you going to have a post back, this is not the best expirience for web.
3. You do not include the `jQuery library` that chosen needs to work.
4. Prefer `CssClass` and not `class`. Both works but for asp.net controls the `CssClass` is the correct one to avoid bugs.

How to find the errors. Open the browser debug tools by right click on page, on the open menu select `Inspect` and then open `Console` and see what errors do you have get and take it from there.

### Reference

[Chosen documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
[Chosen downloads](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/)

### Working Example

I create a minimum example and test it and works.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/Chosen/chosen.jquery.js " ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jQuery/Chosen/chosen.css" />               

<asp:ListBox ID="lstCategoryType" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"  SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen();    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll see all of that